# Intercept the JDBC statements to the database using P6Spy in a hibernate application

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, p6spy

I am developing a hibernate console application and  refer to this article http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/ to setup the P6Spy in order to see what is the actual value of the "(?)" of the SQL generated by the Hibernate.

The setup should work fine as I can see info/debug messages output by P6Spy  during the application starts up. However ,after that, P6Spy seems that it cannot intercept any JDBC statements. From the log generated by hibernate (eg: `Hibernate: insert into Module (projectName, moduleName, projectId) values (?, ?, ?)` ), it can be sure that the JDBC statements are already sent to the database.

The following is my setting:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

- Already specified to use the P6Spy
  driver : `<property
  name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver</property>`
- Already turned on the
  hibernate.show_sql property : 
  `<property
  name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>`

**spy.properties**

- Already changed to use my actual
  database JDBC driver , filter set to
  false , includecategories already
  explicitly set to log anything.

> ```
> module.log=com.p6spy.engine.logging.P6LogFactory
> realdriver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
> filter=false
> dateformat=yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss
> excludecategories=
> includecategories=error, info, batch, debug,statement,commit,rollback,result
> appender=com.p6spy.engine.logging.appender.StdoutLogger
> ```

Do I miss any important setting ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I give up `P6Spy` as it is the old library which the latest version is back to 2003. I resort to use another similar free open source called `log4jdbc` to intercept the JDBC statements , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816853/seeking-for-hibernate-debug-info-improvement/6821195#6821195) for more info if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used P6Spy, but you can get the bind variables to output to your log.  Try putting this in your log4j.properties or xml file.

log4j.category.org.hibernate.type=DEBUG, CONSOLE

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause for this type of problem is that the JDBC driver is loaded before the P6SpyDriver.  You can get around this problem by setting deregisterdrivers=true in spy.properties.

BTW - This issue was fixed in 2.0-alpha-1.