# seeking for Hibernate debug info improvement

Tags: hibernate, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print query string in hibernate with parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710476/print-query-string-in-hibernate-with-parameter-values)

I am using Hibernate as the persistence layer. And I am setting **show_sql** to **true** in order to see the debug info.

However, I am not actually seeing the complete info, because most of the SQL statements as like:

```
insert 
into
    Address
    (address1, address2, city, province) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

the parameters are all a question mark, though I can see some actual data in some select statement's condition part.

I want the info like:

```
insert 
into
    Address
    (address1, address2, city, province) 
values
    ("XXX address1", "XX address2", "XXX city", "XXX province")
```

How can I configure to see those parameter data, or is this a deficiency in hibernate
??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate cannot log the SQL and its parameters in the same line like you want . The logging provided by the Hibernate (by setting `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug` and `log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace` in the log4j configuration) can only log the SQL and the parameters in the different lines likes this  :

```
insert 
into
    Address
    (address1, address2, city, province) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - xxxxxx
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - xxxxxx
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - xxxx
```

You have to use JDBC proxy driver if you want to log the SQL with the parameters in the  same line. I have tried [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) and it can do it  ,and it also can  log the time spent by every SQL statement and log  the lines in the code that cause the SQL statements .

You can refer to this [blog](http://softdevbuilttolast.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/hibernate-sql-logging-log4jdbc-haciendo-log-de-sql-con-hibernate-log4jdbc/) for more information.